# float css only menu - how to modify on section2

Tags: css

Hell o, I have floating menu fixed on top of the screen of my single page web site. When I click the menu item, page slowly scrolls down to appropriate section using jquery. I have  this code for fixed menu on top of the screen:

```
<style>
.fixed_elements{ position:fixed; top:100px; }
        #top-floating-bar{ background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2D2D2D; height: 35px; position: fixed; top: 0; width: 100%; z-index: 100; }
        ul{ padding: 0; margin: 0; }
        .fixed-bar-buttons{ float: left;color: #fff; }
        .fixed-bar-buttons ul { height: 25px; padding-right: 10px; }
        .fixed-bar-buttons ul li{ display: block; float: left; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; height: 25px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px; }
        .fixed-bar-buttons ul li:hover{ background-color: #605F5F; }
        #content-panel{ float: left;margin-top: 40px; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="top-floating-bar">
        <div class="fixed-bar-buttons">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#section2">REFERENCIE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section3">KONTAKT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<div id="section2"> Section2 content</div>
<div id="section3"> Section3 content</div>
...
```

The code is OK and everything works fine. The thing I need to do is to modify the menu when it's on section2 and section3 only and add "UP" button.

When I load the page, I don't need the "UP" button, because It's not possible to go up and it's confusing to be there, so I need it only if I scroll down. Is it possible with CSS(1,2,3) only? Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a Fiddle ? Your code is partial and you are not using half of the classes defined. Where the UP button should be placed ? Inside menus ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible, because you have to fetch the vertical offset of the document to know if the user is at the top of the page, or have scrolled down. The vertical offset is needed to make the decision whether to display the up button or not.

There is a way to do it with JS, but if you're asking for a CSS-only solution, I've given you the bad news already :P